# List mouse over not working

Tags: css, menu, menuitem

The main header menu of **[my site](http://webzer.host56.com/)**  has an hover effect.But when i mouse over to the right of each menu item  the text color is not changing but when i mouse over near the text it changes.

I have tried

```
.menu li:hover{background:#222;
  color:white;}
.menu a:hover{
color:white;
}
```

but this didn't work.work. Please Help to make the hover effect.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the color of the anchor's text when hovering over the `li`. Therefore use the following:

```
.menu li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,i think its compelete:

```
.menu li:hover{
  background:#000;
}
.menu li a:link,
.menu li a:visited{
  color:#000;
}
.menu li:hover a{
  color:#FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
.menu li:hover{
  background:#222;
  color:white
}
.menu li:hover a{
  color:white;
}
```

Comment: haha at first you chose the best answer. If more than one is correct and as good as the other ones, you chose the first one to answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
.menu li:hover{
 background:#222;
 }
 .menu li:hover a{
 color:white;
 }
```

This may be because your anchor has already css defined for itself. you need to override them.